# What's the range of this for loop?

Tags: for-loop

I'm new to CS, and found this code online. What does this blank between two semicolons indicate? What's the range of this for loop? Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0, temp; ; i++)
```

Comment: @OusmaneD. Why did you tag this as Java? It could be any of the C family languages with this for-syntax. Would be best to ask OP to clarify which language they are talking about, or add the language-agnostic tag, since the behavior is the same in all languages as far as I am aware.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Alright, I "Assumed" it was Java for several valid reasons but ok maybe letting the OP clarify would be better. reverted my edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is the *typical* structure of a `for` loop:

```
for(initialization; condition ; increment/decrement)
{
    statement(s);
}
```

but yours is as follows:

```
for(initialization; ; increment)
{
      statement(s);
}
```

As you can see the `condition` part is removed which is completely valid, but this just means that the loop will run *infinitely*.

*Typically* in cases like this, some logic inside the loop block will be responsible to break out of the loop given some condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs for [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for):

> The for statement defines initializer, condition, and iterator sections:
>
> ```
> for (initializer; condition; iterator)
>     body
> ```
>
> All three sections are optional.

Also, from the same source:

> If the condition section **is not present** or the boolean expression evaluates to true, the next loop iteration is executed; otherwise, the loop is exited.

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: why link to doc for C# instead of Java? OP is tagged as Java.

Comment: @kaan There was initially no tag and I misread CS as C#. The Java tag was added by Ousmane D., not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the reference for for at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) you can see the following example.

> The following example defines the infinite for loop:
>
> ```
> for ( ; ; )
> {
>     // Body of the loop.
> }
> ```

The infinity comes from the "the *condition* section" being empty. Again from the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for#the-condition-section):

> The condition section, if present, must be a boolean expression. That expression is evaluated before every loop iteration. If the condition section is not present or the boolean expression evaluates to true, the next loop iteration is executed; otherwise, the loop is exited.

---

Here's a bad clock implemented via a never-ending loop to show the difference between how `i` and `temp` change as the loop progresses.

```
public async static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0, temp; ; i++)
    {
        // 'i' is a) initalised and b) incremented after each 
        // 'temp' is a) *un*initialised and b) doesn't automatically change
        temp = 666;

        Console.WriteLine($"It's now {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay} and this is about {i} seconds after {start.TimeOfDay}. 'temp' is {temp}");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
It's now 09:07:02.9269857 and this is about 0 seconds after 09:07:02.9246017. 'temp' is 666
It's now 09:07:04.0195240 and this is about 1 seconds after 09:07:02.9246017. 'temp' is 666
It's now 09:07:05.0223953 and this is about 2 seconds after 09:07:02.9246017. 'temp' is 666
It's now 09:07:06.0379706 and this is about 3 seconds after 09:07:02.9246017. 'temp' is 666
It's now 09:07:07.0482980 and this is about 4 seconds after 09:07:02.9246017. 'temp' is 666
```